# Como puedo hacer para que en una cadena de caracteres de la que quiero saber su longitud no me cuente los signos de puntuacion?

Tags: c, string

Estoy realizando ejercicios relacionados a caracteres, ya pude realizar un codigo en el cual no me toma en cuenta los espacios en blanco a la hora de contar las palabras de un texto pero, como puedo hacerle para que no me cuenten tambien los signos de puntuacion que el usuario introduzca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En pseudocódigo sería algo así:

1. Inicializa contador a 0
2. Itera por la cadena de entrada y para cada carácter

   2.1 Mira si ese carácter está en la lista de "caracteres a ignorar".

   2.2 Si no lo está, suma 1 al contador

   Hasta que el caracter leído sea el caracter nulo (`'\0'`), lo que indicará que la cadena ha llegado a su final
3. Retorna el contador

Una forma eficiente de mirar si el carácter está en la "lista de caracteres a ignorar" es hacer que esta "lista" sea en realidad otra cadena, con todos los signos de puntuación, el espacio, y aquellos caracteres que no quieras que sean contados. Por ejemplo, la cadena `caracteres_a_ignorar = ".,;¿?()¡! "`

Si lo tienes así, puedes usar:

```
es_ignorable = strchr(caracteres_a_ignorar, caracter);
```

Esta función busca un carácter en una cadena y retorna un puntero a `char` (ese es el tipo con que debes declarar `es_ignorable`). Ese puntero apuntará al carácter si lo encontró, o será `NULL` si no lo encontró. Así que te bastará comparar eso con `NULL` y si es igual es que no se encontró, por tanto no era "ignorable" y por tanto hay que contarlo.